# How to know how many *args the user input into a Python function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to find a simple solution to know how many arguments have the user input into the *args of a Python function but to no avail. So I guess it would be faster to ask the experts here.

Say:

```
def foo(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print "we have:", arg
```

So is there a way to know that if the user does `foo(1,2,3,4)` we know that he/she has inputted 4 arguments?

Thank you for your attention and help!

Comment: `len(args)` should work since `args` is a normal tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len).

```
In [1]: def foo(*args):
   ...:     print(type(args))
   ...:     print(len(args))
   ...:     

In [2]: foo(1, 2, 3, 4)
<class 'tuple'>
4
```

The type of `args` can be found out with the built-in function [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `args` is probably a sequence or a collection, you could just use [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) to get the number of items.

```
def foo(*args):
    print "we have", len(args), "args"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is as simple as `len(args)` because the `args` is nothing but a tuple so you can apply other operations as well which are applicable to tuples.